I want to add my own images to this project that traces the contour lines
i want to add my own images to this project that traces the contour lines how do i go about doing that
here is the link to the project: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TracingContourLinesInPhotographicImages/

I tried to download the source code to look but I get Service Temporarily Unavailable when I click on the download source code link inside the CDF file. Looks like site is down now. But if you can find the source code, you can post it here and someone can show you how to change the image. I do not know why the source code is not inside the CDF file anymore. It used to be there long time ago. Having to download the CDF file and then having to download the source code again is not good way to do it.

Why not simply EdgeDetect[myImage]?

If you want to somewhat reproduce the linked demonstration, maybe use this answer and change the ColorFunction to SunsetColors example notebook

Check this post
